# Using .splice() to create a substitute variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function proposed by freeCodeCamp that operates as follows:

> "You are given two arrays and an index. Copy each element of the first
> array into the second array, in order. Begin inserting elements at
> index n of the second array. Return the resulting array. The input
> arrays should remain the same after the function runs."

Solution being

```
function f(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let dummy_arr2 = arr2.slice();
  a2.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);
  return dummy_arr2;
};
```

Now, when I simply use `dummy_arr2 = arr2` on the second line, without the `slice()` operator, `arr2` doesn't remain unchanged. Why is this?

Comment: `.slice()` returns a _copy_ of the original array whereas `arr2 = arr1` will make `arr2` point to the _same_ array which `arr1` points to.

Comment: The wording of that question leaves a lot to be desired. If the arrays should "remain the same" then "copy ... into" is clearly misleading.